Would knowledge of a game be considered non-benefical knowledge?
For example, if I know what Y lvl diamonds spawn in Minecraft, and I were to share it with others, would this be considered Non-beneficial knowledge? Or have I gotten the concept of it entirely wrong?
(I have no idea what tag to put so I put halal-haram)

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your question, you should ask yourself what is beneficial in sharing this knowledge.

There is no sin in such knowledge. But as muslims we should not do anything that is neutral(neither bad nor good) as it would be a waste of time.
The above example is a neutral one.
But if you earn something from it like -
Which trees are found where, how different items are used, etc then it maybe useful in real life too.
But if under any circumstances it is beneficial to anyone then that would be useful.
But I don't think your example is anything useful in real world or islam.
